# Rails sessions when stop / start server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When I stop Rails server and start it again, the session hash still has objects.

Why is happening that ?

Thank you in advance, Ele

Answer (score 1):

try `rake db:drop`

then after that `rake db:migrate` to migrate your database from schema

otherwise check your seeds file to see if you have any seed data.

Answer (score 1):

By default you store the sessions to a cookie. That means that the data are on the client side. So even if you restart your server, the data remains.

check [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage) for the docs.

You can of course store your session in various [session stores](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session)